# VB6 Recordset update

Tags: vb6, ado, recordset

I am running a vb6 program that is looping through many records in a database table and entering a date into a field.  This will take many hours to run.

I am noticing that the number of records in the table is increasing by 1 every few seconds and then reducing by 1 (going back to the original count).  Is there a reason for this?

I am using a VB6 recordset and the update function i.e. rs.update.  I am not inserting any new records.

The code is as follows:

```
rs.Open "select reference,value1,datefield from datetable where field1 = 'value1' " & _
    "order by reference", objAuditCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic

Do While Not rs.EOF
    intReadCount = intReadCount + 1
    DoEvents
    If Not IsNull(rs("value1")) Then
        testArray = Split(rs("value1"), ",")
        rs2.Open "SELECT Date FROM TBL_TestTable WHERE Record_URN = '" & testArray(1) & "'", objSystemCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
        If rs2.EOF Then

        End If
        If Not rs2.EOF Then
            rs("DateField") = Format$(rs2("Date"), "dd mmm yy h:mm:ss")
            rs.Update
            intWriteCount = intWriteCount + 1
        End If
    rs2.Close
    Else    
    End If

rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Comment: I can see no reason for the record count to be increasing, but just curious, why aren't you executing SQL statements to update the information vs looping through the records? Then you could update a bunch at once.

Comment: Why not create a Stored Procedure and then execute it via code? This should improve you process time a little.

Comment: I am thinking that there could be an additional row for caching purposes maybe?

Comment: How are you determining that the record count is changing?

Comment: CraigJ, I am simply running a count in SQL Studio Manager i.e. select count(*) from datetable? Pressing the execute button every second, the count occasionally increases by one record and then immediately decreases by one record? Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What would be more interesting is what data is in this extra row. In any case, the bottom line is that if it is not actually causing a problem for you then don't worry about it. You could notify Microsoft about the issue and see what they say.  They are meant to provide support.

Comment: @CraigJ MS won't provide support probably since it is using a VB 6 application.  They don't support this anymore.  Would possibly depend on the database version but likely they wouldn't touch it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can greatly reduce your SQL work here.

```
If Not IsNull(rs("value1")) Then
        testArray = Split(rs("value1"), ",")
        rs2.Open "SELECT Date FROM TBL_TestTable WHERE Record_URN = '" & testArray(1) & "'", objSystemCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
        If rs2.EOF Then

        End If
        If Not rs2.EOF Then
            rs("DateField") = Format$(rs2("Date"), "dd mmm yy h:mm:ss")
            rs.Update
            intWriteCount = intWriteCount + 1
        End If
rs2.Close
```

You're essentially, it looks to me(I haven't used VB6 & ADO in 10 years), loading up your record initial recordset, checking a value, and if that value is not null running a second select THEN updating the recordset....
You can instead of doing all this just create a command object
Declare these before your loops
`dim objComm`
`set objComm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")`

```
objComm.ActiveConnection =  objSystemCon.ActiveCon 'I think this is your connn.
objComm.CommandType = 1 'adCmdText
```

Use this in your loop

```
objComm.CommandText = "UPDATE DateTable SET DateField = (SELECT Date FROM TBL_TestTable WHERE Record_URN = '" & testArray(1) & "'")
objComm.Execute
```

Rather than doing a 2nd discreet select, pulling the data in, then doing an update and pushing it back out just push out an update statement.  This should speed up the processing of your records.....I know i used to write stuff in VB6 like this a long while back :)

So your code should now read like

```
dim objComm
set objComm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")` 

    objComm.ActiveConnection =  objSystemCon.ActiveCon 'I think this is your connn.
    objComm.CommandType = 1 'adCmdText

rs.Open "select reference,value1,datefield from datetable where field1 = 'value1' " & _
    "order by reference", objAuditCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic

Do While Not rs.EOF
    intReadCount = intReadCount + 1
    DoEvents
    If Not IsNull(rs("value1")) Then
        testArray = Split(rs("value1"), ",")
    objComm.CommandText = "UPDATE DateTable SET DateField = (SELECT Date FROM TBL_TestTable WHERE Record_URN = '" & testArray(1) & "'")
    objComm.Execute 

    End If

rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

your select statement is still there as you can see, it's a sub select now, the advantage being huge, you're not drawing records to the server, then updating them.  You're sending the server a statement to do the updating.  You're cutting your trips in half.

Hope this made sense.

Comment: Jordan, I realise there are better ways of writing the code.  However, the original question asked specifically about why the record count keeps incresasing by 1 record every few seconds and then reducing by 1 record immediately.  I am establishing the record count by running an SQL query in SQL Studio Manager.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I realize that sorry, just had to take the opportunity to make the suggestion.
There must be something else causing it.  Do you have an index on the table?  Perhaps the constant updates are causing the index to return some slightly divergent value.  I would suspect there is NOT an extra row being created.  

If you really believe there is an extra row I suppose you could copy the table to another one with all the data and run a query to pull out ones that exist on the processing table vs the static backup copy.  This would be very slow and I don't think it would show anything.

Comment: Thanks Jordan.  I have been thinking about this all day.  I have run some tests on the data and although it returns more rows when the program is running; it does not return any rows when I attempt to run a comparison i.e. select * from datetable where reference not in (select reference from datetabletest).  The table datetabletest was created before I run the program.  When I add a Primary Key the problem is no longer there i.e. the count is consistent.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I wasn't able to access this thread this morning but it seems to have reappeared.

Comment: Well a primary key would add a clustered index to the table.  Perhaps you had no index before?  I suppose that some row locking might cause a divergent row count.  Having an index would allow it to access the row count regardless of the table level locks.  I know a pending transaction can give incorrect row counts depending, so I'd imagine it's possible. If you're familiar with ACID the I is Isolation so perhaps the server is not dealing with that row while it is actually being updated.  Now that i think about it an update has an implicit transaction that would probably block the reader.

Comment: There are more records returned when the program runs.  If there was a locking issue then I would expect the query to return fewer recrds.  As I said the it occurs when there is a clustered index and no primary key.  It does not happen when there is a clustered index and a primary key.

Comment: Do you have any update triggers on the data table.  This could account for your adding/removing issue.

Comment: Ok At this point what I'd suggest is running the SQL Server Profiler.  You can see what is really going on.  Do you have any experience using this tool?

Comment: I spoke to the DBA and we did some debugging using the SQL Profiler.  There was nothing conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: take out the DoEvents statement. If you are using it to get screen refresh, the periodically do a manual refresh of your GUI after, say, 1000 iterations of the loop.

The reason why this may be causing an issue is that other code you may have no control over might be being executed when you call DoEvents.