# VB6 Recordsets and SQL count

Tags: vb6

I am noticing that the number of records in a database table (select reference from datetable) suddenly increases when I start running the program below even though there are no new records added.  Please note that I establish that the number of rows increases by running a query in SQL Studio Manager i.e. select reference from datetable.  When the program stops; the number of records falls back to the original level.  Here is the code.  Why does this happen? There is no Primary Key in the table though Reference is unique.

```
rs.Open "select reference,value1,datefield from datetable where field1 = 'value1' " & _     
                "order by reference", objAuditCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic  
Do While Not rs.EOF
     intReadCount = intReadCount + 1
     DoEvents
     If Not IsNull(rs("value1")) Then
         testArray = Split(rs("value1"), ",") 
        rs2.Open "SELECT Date FROM TBL_TestTable WHERE Record_URN = '" & testArray(1) & "'", objSystemCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
         If rs2.EOF Then
          End If
         If Not rs2.EOF Then
             rs("DateField") = Format$(rs2("Date"), "dd mmm yy h:mm:ss")
             rs.Update
             intWriteCount = intWriteCount + 1
         End If
     rs2.Close
     Else
         End If
  rs.MoveNext
 Loop
 rs.Close
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747341/vb6-recordset-update ?

Comment: You should rewrite this question and take out the part about the risks of running a recordset update on a table without a primary key and focus on the table record count part and you might get better answers.

Comment: Shane, thanks.  I have done this.  C-Pounr Guru, I can't see the original question anymore.  When I click on the link I get an error.  Yes, it is the same question, but probably worded slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confused, but if you are referring to the total given by "intReadCount" against how many rows you have in the table then it looks as though you are not correctly clearing this value. At the beginning of the procedure you would want to set "intReadCount" back to 0 before starting, you should then get constant results.

Updated: See comments below

Comment: Matt, No I am not referring to intReadCount.  I am logged onto sql studio manager and I am entering a query into the query window (and executing).  "select reference from datetable" returns more rows when the program is running.  Then when I run "select reference from datetable"  afterwards it reverts back to the original count.  Could this be due to the fact that there is no Primary Key? The field 'reference' is unique.

Comment: @w0051977 This is not related to the presence of PK's, I would suggest taking a dump of the increased query and then comparing this back to the final query to highlight which are the extra rows, as there is no PK I suggest ordering the query so you can sort out those rows.

Comment: Matt, it does not occur when I add a PK so it has to be the fact that there is no PK.  I tried what you suggested: select reference from datetable where reference not in (select reference from datetablebackup).  datetablebackup was taken before I ran the program.  There were no rows returned when I ran the query.  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 I wouldn't worry about it too much then, likely a glitch in the program, or it may be there to serve some other unknown purpose.